# Storing data from nested json data in python

Tags: python, json, nested

I want to access 'dl_dst' values from all the sets in this json data
i can get dl_dst data but it stores 3 time of each data point back to back. What is mistake i have made?

```
{'1': [{'actions': ['OUTPUT:1'],
    'byte_count': 238,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 833000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:02',
              'in_port': 2},
    'packet_count': 3,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:2'],
    'byte_count': 140,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 828000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:02',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'in_port': 1},
    'packet_count': 2,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:1'],
    'byte_count': 238,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 809000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:03',
              'in_port': 2},
    'packet_count': 3,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:2'],
    'byte_count': 140,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 807000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:03',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'in_port': 1},
    'packet_count': 2,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:1'],
    'byte_count': 238,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 787000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:04',
              'in_port': 2},
    'packet_count': 3,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:2'],
    'byte_count': 140,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 786000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:04',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'in_port': 1},
    'packet_count': 2,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:CONTROLLER'],
    'byte_count': 1944,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 582000000,
    'duration_sec': 168,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 80,
    'match': {},
    'packet_count': 27,
    'priority': 0,
    'table_id': 0}]}
```

Here is the python code i wrote

```
import requests
import pprint
import json


url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/19yp59'
get_data = requests.get(url)
get_data_json = get_data.json()
data = get_data_json['1']

Dest_Mac = []

for k in data:

 for i in k['match']:
     Dest_Mac.append(k['match']['dl_dst'])


print(Dest_Mac)
```

This is the results for this code

['00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04', '00:00:00:00:00:04', '00:00:00:00:00:04']

Notice that each data point is printed 3 times.

Comment: If you want to remove duplicate list record try this `print(list(set(Dest_Mac)))`

Comment: Its not repeat everywhere. for example the second and third data points are the same copy of first data point. the fifth and sixth data point is same copy of fourth data point.

Comment: The result should be like this ['00:00:00:00:00:01','00:00:00:00:00:02','00:00:00:00:00:01','00:00:00:00:00:03','00:00:00:00:00:01','00:00:00:00:00:04'] should be 6 data points instead of 18

Comment: Update your question with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Your inner loop iterates over the keys in each `match` dictionary, but it prints the value associated with the `dl_dts` key each time it finds a new key - hence the three repeats of each value.

There's no need to iterate at all: you already have the dict, so all you need to do is print out the value of that key - assuming it exists.

This code therefore uses the dict's `get` method to return `None` when the key is absent and there's nothing to add to the list.

```
data = {'1': [{'actions': ['OUTPUT:1'],
    'byte_count': 238,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 833000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:02',
              'in_port': 2},
    'packet_count': 3,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
# remainder of data omitted for brevity ...
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:CONTROLLER'],
    'byte_count': 1944,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 582000000,
    'duration_sec': 168,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 80,
    'match': {},
    'packet_count': 27,
    'priority': 0,
    'table_id': 0}]}

result = []
for item in data['1']:
    this = item['match'].get('dl_dst')
    if this:
        result.append(this)

print(result)
```

This seems to give the output you want:

```
['00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04']
```

Comment: A pleasure. I'd appreciate it it you would mark the answer as "Accepted" if you are happy it solves your problem - remember, points mean prizes (well, not really, but it helps nudge my reputation up a little).

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to following:

```
for k in data:
    for i,j in k['match'].items():
        if i == "dl_dst":
            Dest_Mac.append(j)

print(Dest_Mac)
```

Output:

```
['00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04']
```

Problem is with your inner for loop. It prints the value of **dl_dst** each time it finds a new key.

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Answer (score 0):

By doing the following :

```
for i in k['match']:
    Dest_Mac.append(k['match']['dl_dst'])
```

you are iterating among all the keys present in `k['match']` and therefore appending `k['match']['dl_dst']` each time. With your example, it triples the desired output.

You should replace with:

```
if 'dl_dst' in k['match'].keys():
        Dest_Mac.append(k['match']['dl_dst'])
```

**Output**

```
['00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> data_json = {'1': [{'actions': ['OUTPUT:1'],
    'byte_count': 238,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 833000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:02',
              'in_port': 2},
    'packet_count': 3,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:2'],
    'byte_count': 140,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 828000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:02',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'in_port': 1},
    'packet_count': 2,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:1'],
    'byte_count': 238,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 809000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:03',
              'in_port': 2},
    'packet_count': 3,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:2'],
    'byte_count': 140,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 807000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:03',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'in_port': 1},
    'packet_count': 2,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:1'],
    'byte_count': 238,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 787000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:04',
              'in_port': 2},
    'packet_count': 3,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:2'],
    'byte_count': 140,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 786000000,
    'duration_sec': 138,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 104,
    'match': {'dl_dst': '00:00:00:00:00:04',
              'dl_src': '00:00:00:00:00:01',
              'in_port': 1},
    'packet_count': 2,
    'priority': 1,
    'table_id': 0},
   {'actions': ['OUTPUT:CONTROLLER'],
    'byte_count': 1944,
    'cookie': 0,
    'duration_nsec': 582000000,
    'duration_sec': 168,
    'flags': 0,
    'hard_timeout': 0,
    'idle_timeout': 0,
    'length': 80,
    'match': {},
    'packet_count': 27,
    'priority': 0,
    'table_id': 0}]}
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> out = []
>>> data = data_json[1]
>>> for d in data:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k == 'match':
            for ik,iv in v.items():
                if ik == 'dl_dst':
                    out.append(iv)
```

using list comprehension:

```
>>> [iv for d in data for k,v in d.items() if k=='match' for ik,iv in v.items() if ik == 'dl_dst']
['00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04']
```

Comment: This code works, but the iteration over the items of the dictionaries is completely unnecessary. When you don't know whether a key exists you can either test for it with `key in dict` or use the dict's `get` method to apply a default value.